# Index not found in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This query execute in 8 s.:

```
SELECT segment,
    [segstart]
FROM dbo.CmsCallHistory WITH (INDEX(CmsCallHistory_SGSTRT))
WHERE segstart between '2015-09-20' and '2015-09-30'
```

But this query ~3 minutes

```
SELECT segment,
    [segstart]
FROM dbo.CmsCallHistory
WHERE segstart between '2015-09-20' and '2015-09-30'
```

Data rows count ~120k

In second query execution plan I can't see index, but only Table Scan cost 98%: 
[image: Second query]

In first query execution plan I see that segstart index is used: 
[image: First query]

Columns total: ~20

Rows total: 40296998

So what's wrong ?

Comment: We'll need to see more information such as execution plans, table and index definitions and information about how many rows exists in total etc. to be able to help.

Comment: Either table statistics is wrong, saved query plan is wrong or SQL optimizer makes wrong decision. Run `update statistics dbo.data with fullscan` and immediately after that your slower query - does something improve?

Comment: maybe a good solution for you - create clustered index?

Comment: Try adding segment to your index as included column (and create a clustered index as @Devart suggest)

Comment: Please share index details (CmsCallHistory_SGSTRT) and if there are other indexes ... and table structure too!

From the details available I can see that both the indexes are not ideal.

Comment: Now i started @Arvo suggest. After I finish, when update index structure

Comment: update statistics not help :(

Comment: @user3093010  Have you tried creating a Covered Index, like I showed below.... can you share the plan after that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on second execution plan I would suggest to create a Covered Index. This will get rid of KeyLookUpID from the execution plan and it should resolve the issue.
Also [refer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/what-i-can-do-to-speed-up-key-lookup-in-my-query)  this for covered index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Name
ON dbo.CmsCallHistory (segstart)
INCLUDE (segment.. include your other columns from select statement);
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP INDEX CmsCallHistory_SGSTRT ON dbo.CmsCallHistory
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CmsCallHistory_SGSTRT ON dbo.CmsCallHistory (segstart)
GO

--DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
--GO

SELECT segment, [segstart]
FROM dbo.CmsCallHistory
WHERE segstart BETWEEN '2015-09-20' AND '2015-09-30'
```

Comment: clustered index + heap (check your images) on the same table? no way ;)